# Checking if a whole word is in a text file in python without regex

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to find if a word is in a file and not if it is part of a partial word. For example if `word = 'tes'` and 'test' is in the word list, I want it to return False. I've found where you can do it via regex, but since I haven't covered that portion in what I've learned, I'd like to see if I can accomplish this without it.

This is what I have so far:

```
WORDLIST_FILENAME = "words.txt"

def isValidWord(word, hand, wordList):
    letters = {}
    for i in word:
    letters[i] = letters.get(i, 0) + 1

    if word.upper() in open(wordList).read():
        for i in letters:
            if i in hand:
                if hand[i] >= letters[i]:
                    continue
                else:
                    return False
            else:
                return False
        return True
    else:
        return False


word = 'tes'
hand = {'t': 3, 'a': 1, 's': 1, 'i': 1, 'n': 1, 'g': 1}

print(isValidWord(word, hand, 'words.txt'))
```

This returns True even though 'tes' isn't actually in word.txt. I know why, because I'm checking if that string is in the file period, but I don't know how to work around that.

Comment: For starters, your code is incorrectly indented. Please fix the indentation.

Comment: I don’t see any code to locate the target word, only one line of code to check if the target word exists in the file.

Comment: wouldn't you want to split the string into words and then check if word=="tes"?

Comment: the solution will not be difficult. But you need to find out all positions of the target word. For example, if the position of the target word is at X, then check if wordlist[X-1] and wordlist[X+len(targetword)+1] is valid breaking token.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to check out the `in` keyword, since it seems like what youre going for.

Here's a quick example:

```
>>> word = "some"
>>> sentence = "This is a sentence with some words."
>>> word in sentence
True
```

Since you don't want it to match partial words, you could remove all non-alphabetic characters, then `split` your string:

```
>>> sentence = ''.join(char for char in sentence if char.isalpha() or char.isspace()).split()
>>> "words" in sentence
True
>>> "word" in sentence
False
```

Honestly though, I would just use regex for this.

Comment: Can't you just use split this way: `s = "this is a test tested tester"
[word for word in s.split() if word=='tes']`

Comment: Yes absolutely you could, it would work, and I would do that for a one-off. However I'm assuming that OP is going to be checking the file for more than one word. You don't want to create the same list multiple times.

Comment: I'm actually creating a mini version of scrabble, so I'll only be checking for one at a time, so in this case, just splitting it worked great! I'll definitely keep the rest in mind for the future, I simply hadn't thought of splitting the words into a list and comparing against the list

Answer (score 2):

Just to lay out yet another solution, how about

```
if line.startswith('test ') or line.endswith(' test\n') or ' test ' in line:
    # ...
```

This is arguably clunky but it does avoid using regular expressions or splitting the entire line just to find one word. Examining the start and end of the line before even analyzing the entire line might shave off a few cycles, though I haven't done any timings.

This presupposes that the lines are regularly spaced (one space between words, no tabs or etc, no punctuation). If your requirements differ, normalizing the line by splitting it on sequences of whitespace + optional  punctuation is probably the way to go.

Comment: Thanks. This is an acceptable answer if you have words within spaces.

Answer (score -1):

You can use string.find method. It return index of string found else return -1.  For ex:-

```
str  = "This is a Test method". 
a = str.find("test")
if a>=0:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Comment: This does not check if the fragment is a part of another word.